# Is different background color for mobile foundation topbar possible?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I would like to use a different background color for the Foundation topbar menu in mobile view compared to the desktop view. In the settings file you have $topbar-dropdown-bg to set the color but this is the same for both views. I have tried the following code:

```
$topbar-dropdown-bg: white;
@media only screen and (max-width : 40em) { 
   $topbar-dropdown-bg: #dc2a87;
}
```

But the problem is that all views give the color background but this should be only in the mobile view?

Answer (score 0):

Use scss media query for changing foundation top-bar.

```
   @media #{$small-only} { }
```

Use it with the bg-background variable.

```
   @media #{$small-only} { 
   $topbar-dropdown-bg :#fff;
   }
```